# Как хранить большое количество данных в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю игру на Unity для запоминания иностранных слов. Нужно хранить информацию о слове: его перевод, количество верных, неверных угадываний и другую статистику. Слово - ключ к данным. Таких данных получается около десяти, а самих слов будут сотни. Какие способы есть хранить всю эту информацию и обновлять ее во время игры?

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте SQLite. Бд будет хранится в самом приложении, удобно для офлайн работы.